# Bootstrap popover class not working properly on javascript generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a select that will have a fixed height (done) and which will show a popover when hover on options.

First I created a select using a plugin : http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

That's working fine, and here's the code so far :

```
<select id="selectUse" class="form-control selectpicker" name="selectUse"
                                    style="height: auto;">
     <optgroup label="OptGroup One">
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
          <option value="value">Option</option>
     </optgroup>
```

That's all working fine.

Then I want to add the popover class on it from Bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

So here's what I had to do in jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        size: 10,
        dropupAuto: false
    });


    $(document).on('mouseover','.popoverClass', function() {
        $(this).popover();
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
        $(this).addClass('popoverClass');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle','popover');
        $(this).attr('data-trigger','hover');
        $(this).attr('data-content','test');
        $(this).attr('tabindex','0');
        $(this).attr('title','test');
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', 'li', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('popoverClass');
        $(this).removeAttr('data-toggle');
        $(this).removeAttr('data-trigger');
        $(this).removeAttr('data-content');
    });

});
```

Now this is somewhat working. I can see the popover on the edge of the select small window that's been opened when I hover on a li element for the **second** time and I think that's because I only activate popover(); when mouse enters a li that has .popoverClass, which won't happen the first time (since this is when it adds the .popoverClass), obviously. But I have no idea how to access a delegated element without an event.

Also, I can only see the popover on the edge of the select small window, and I'd like to change the style of this. I have no idea how to do it, since it generates a div via javascript, and I don't know how to control it.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind the event handler. You could use `delegate()` so you don't have to (if you have wrote the original function), but since you're using a lib, just rebind the handler on the element after it's created on the page.. Something like

```
$('.popover-class').popover({ ... });
```

In a callback after you dynamically create the content.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your answer.
"In a callback after you dynamically create the content" ?
How do I do this ?

Comment: Say I have a `<div>` on my page with the class of `className`, and in my javascript I have a function like `$('.className').click(function() { ... })`. If I use javascript to then append another `<div class="className"></div>` on the page, this one won't have the click event handler bound to it, unless you either a) delegate it to the class or b) rebind it.